# linux fd is int, does it mean there's no more change to create 2^32 fds in one processs?

Tags: linux, file, int, restriction

Is this the designed limitation? So int type length is the limitation of linux system, even in far future?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all remember that `int` is *signed* so on a two's-complement system there is (2^31)-1 number of possible values (assuming that `int` is 32 bits, which is usually the case). But most systems limit the number of descriptors even more than that, usually to something like 65536 or possibly even lower.